# Travel time from Heathrow to King's Cross

Tags: uk, public-transport, transportation, london, lhr

What's the travel time, by tube, from Heathrow to King's Cross Station in London and how often does the tube run between those locations?

Comment: Doesn't the [TFL journey planner](https://www.tfl.gov.uk/plan-a-journey/) answer your question(s)?

Comment: The answer to your second question depends on the day and the time of the journey. Use TFL's journey planner as suggested by @MH and insert the details of your journey.